# Provide parameters to scp with xargs

Tags: scp, xargs

When I run `svn st | awk '{print $2}'`, I get:

```
a.py
b.py
c.py
```

Then I want to `scp` these files to a remote server. I have tried:

```
svn st | awk '{print $2}' | xargs scp my_name@my_server:~/
```

But it doesn't work. What is the right command to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this.  should work with recent versions of xargs.

`svn st | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -iz scp z my_name@my_server:`

alternately, you could just loop though the files.

`for file in $(svn st | awk '{print $2}'); do scp $file my_name@my_server: ; done`

Comment: Thank you Tim. I googled a lot and found the solution: `svn st | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -J % scp % my_name@my_server:~/` I should have read the man page of `xargs` before asking ;)

Comment: And your solution works too! But there is a typo, it's `-Iz` not `-iz`

Comment: what OS are you using?  I use `-iz` on Solaris, and it always works.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: got it. I'm on Mac OS, Lion. I see the xargs wikipedia page is also using `-I`.

Comment: [POSIX xargs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/xargs.html) has `-I`. The AIX (6.1) man page says `-i` is obsolete and `-I` should be used. Solaris 10 (and 9) has both `-i` and `-I`.

Comment: Ah, my knowledge is obsolete!  I've been using `-i` since Solaris 2.5.  getting old is a sad affair, my friends. :)

Answer (score 5):

The reason this doesn't work is that you're telling `xargs` to run

```
scp my_name@my_server:~/ a.py b.py c.py
```

The order of the arguments doesn't correspond to what you want to do. One solution is to force the file names to appear before the destination on the command line. This requires GNU xargs (i.e. Linux or Cygwin). While we're at it, we can pass `-d '\n'` to ensure that any file name that doesn't contain newlines will work (without `-d`, xargs expects some weird quoting of its input); this is not necessary if you work with typical software source trees, in which file names tend to be very tame.

```
svn st | awk '{print $2}' |
xargs -d\\n -I{} scp {} my_name@my_server:~/
```

A downside of this method is that `scp` is called separately for every file. If you're copying a lot of small files, that can make a significant difference, as an SSH connection takes a little while to establish. You can greatly shorten the per-connection time by using an SSH master connection (that's outstide the scope of this answer, see the manual, especially the `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options in `.ssh/config`).

A way to force the arguments to be in the right place is to go through an intermediate shell. This is a general technique to reorder arguments when using `xargs` or `find … -exec`.

```
svn st | awk '{print $2}' |
xargs -d\\n sh -c 'scp "$@" "$0" my_name@my_server:~/
```

Another possibility is to use `rsync` instead of `scp`. You can pass `rsync` a list of file names on standard input. Since `rsync` expects a list of patterns and not a list of file names, this requires that your file names do not contain any wildcard characters (specifically, no newlines, no `\[*?` and no initial `#` or `;`).

```
svn st | awk '{print $2}' |
rsync -a --include-from=- --exclude='*' . my_name@my_server:~/
```