# can not copy more than 29 files to the target server using shell script

Tags: shell-script, scp, sftp

I want to move more than 1K files from one server to another 
but just 29 files were copied and can not copy the reset 
and its same when I am using the SCP

```
#scripts for backup
#sripts prepared by dhafer abudarag86348@gmail.com
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +"%Y%m")
/usr/bin/expect<<EOF
  cd /home/mdsp/lcftp/templc/sag/sa/run/sa/10.157.78.40
  spawn  bash -c "/usr/bin/scp *$date*.log root@10.157.78.143:/tmp/dhafer"
  expect "Password:"
  send "Zain@123\r"
  expect eof
EOF
```

and the

```
#scripts for backup
#sripts prepared by dhafer 0592996292 abudarag86348@gmail.com
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m")
HOST=10.157.78.143
PORT=22
USER=root
PASSWORD=Zain@123
SOURCE_FILE=/home/mdsp/lcftp/templc/sag/sa/run/sa/10.157.78.40/*$DATE*
TARGET_DIR=/tmp/dhafer
/usr/bin/expect<<EOD
  spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=$PORT $USER@$HOST
  expect "password:"
  send "$PASSWORD\r"
  expect "sftp>"
  send "put $SOURCE_FILE $TARGET_DIR\r"
  expect "sftp>"
  send "bye\r"
```

Can you please help me to check?

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer your question, couldn't you archive all of the files into a tarball and just copy that over?

Comment: hi sorry didnt get you

Answer (score 2):

Probably your command line is too long. You should run several smaller `scp` commands for example using `xargs`. But your expect/password script would make this a bit hard to code.

Maybe here you would find a "xargs-like" scp solution
[Provide parameters to scp with xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24846/provide-parameters-to-scp-with-xargs)

Or use a find, tar, ssh pipe:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$date*.log" -print0 |\
    tar -czvf backup.tar.gz --null -T - |\
    ssh user@host "cd /tmp/dhafer && tar xvzf -"
```

Alternatively you could try `rsync` without shell globbing:

```
rsync --include="*$date*.log" --exclude="*" ./ root@10.157.78.143:/tmp/dhafer/
```

**Note** in any case it would be helpful if you could use ssh's public key authentication.

Comment: you gave me another good idea, can you help to provide my script to compress the files then scp it