# How to use variable in scp command for multiple files

Tags: shell-script, scp

I tried to do `scp` multiple files. When I do `ls {aaa,bbb}*_list.txt`, I could see only the selective files. However, If I assign this to a variable and tried to use it in `scp` command it doesn't work.

I have tried as below

```
files_to_scp="{aaa,bbb}*_list.txt"
scp $files_to_scp user@host:.
```

It throws error `{aaa,bbb}*_list.txt: No such file or directory`. But if just copy the error path (`{aaa,bbb}*_list.txt`) and do `ls`, it shows the file. What could be the mistake here.

Comment: Im alternatively using this approach for now. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24846/provide-parameters-to-scp-with-xargs

Answer (score 3):

The [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) syntax `{aaa,bbb}` must have the braces and the `,` character to be unquoted for it to expand to a valid/possible set of files. In the OP, the  `"{aaa,bbb}*_list.txt"` is kept intact as a literal string and not expanded at all.

Also storing a brace expansion in a variable and interpolating that variable to expand the brace will never work because, the brace expansion happens before any other shell expansions, i.e. by the time you expect the `$files_to_scp` to be expand the brace, the shell has already crossed the point where it would expand the braces

Using a variable is *not* a right approach for holding multiple words. It will fail badly if you have filenames that contain spaces or other shell special characters. Use an array type and a proper quoted expansion

```
files_to_scp=({aaa,bbb}*_list.txt)
```

and now use the result as

```
scp "${files_to_scp[@]}" user@host:.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable (`files_to_scp`) is holding the literal string `"{aaa,bbb}*_list.txt"`, **NOT** an expansion of all matching files.   bash doesn't expand braces on scalar variable assignments.

bash does, however, expand them for arrays.  Use an array instead.

e.g.

```
files_to_scp=( {aaa,bbb}*_list.txt )
scp "${files_to_scp[@]}" user@host:.
```

---

Here's a (simplified, practical) example & explanation, showing what's happening:

1. I created a bunch of files matching your pattern

   ```
   $ mkdir spike
   $ cd spike
   $ touch {aaa,bbb}{01..10}_list.txt
   $ ls
   aaa01_list.txt  aaa05_list.txt  aaa09_list.txt  bbb03_list.txt  bbb07_list.txt
   aaa02_list.txt  aaa06_list.txt  aaa10_list.txt  bbb04_list.txt  bbb08_list.txt
   aaa03_list.txt  aaa07_list.txt  bbb01_list.txt  bbb05_list.txt  bbb09_list.txt
   aaa04_list.txt  aaa08_list.txt  bbb02_list.txt  bbb06_list.txt  bbb10_list.txt
   ```
2. your variable assignment stores the literal string:

   ```
   $ files_to_scp="{aaa,bbb}*_list.txt"
   $ declare -p files_to_scp
   declare -- files_to_scp="{aaa,bbb}*_list.txt"
   ```
3. and bash does the same without the quotes:

   ```
   $ files_to_scp={aaa,bbb}*_list.txt
   $ declare -p files_to_scp
   declare -- files_to_scp="{aaa,bbb}*_list.txt"
   ```
4. using an array, each matching filename is stored as an element of the array.

   ```
   $ files_to_scp=( {aaa,bbb}*_list.txt )
   $ declare -p files_to_scp
   declare -a files_to_scp=([0]="aaa01_list.txt" [1]="aaa02_list.txt" [2]="aaa03_list.txt" [3]="aaa04_list.txt" [4]="aaa05_list.txt" [5]="aaa06_list.txt" [6]="aaa07_list.txt" [7]="aaa08_list.txt" [8]="aaa09_list.txt" [9]="aaa10_list.txt" [10]="bbb01_list.txt" [11]="bbb02_list.txt" [12]="bbb03_list.txt" [13]="bbb04_list.txt" [14]="bbb05_list.txt" [15]="bbb06_list.txt" [16]="bbb07_list.txt" [17]="bbb08_list.txt" [18]="bbb09_list.txt" [19]="bbb10_list.txt")
   ```

Comment: I haven't found an exact dupe for your question yet, but questions about this come up fairly frequently here.  Try searching for [bash variable expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=bash+variable+expansion)

Comment: also, a useful rule of thumb. when defining a variable, ask yourself "do i want this variable to hold multiple values/filenames/whatever?".   If yes, then use an array.  Otherwise you will run into all manner of word-splitting problems that would be easily avoided just by using an array.